# Ruby DSL: Can you pass a block to an object

Tags: ruby, dsl

I'm quite new to Ruby and just exploring around with DSL.  I'm wondering if this is possible in Ruby, and if so, how would one do this?

```
melissa = Player.new
melissa do
  on :turn do
    puts "It's my turn!"
  end

  on :win do
    puts "I win! Hahahaha"
  end
end
```

Excuse me if this has been asked before. I'm not sure what to search for this problem. Searching for DSL yields other things.

Comment: What's the 'on' construct?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Let's suppose there's a method inside the `Player` class: `def on(event) ... `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can. Here's a sample, try to modify it:

```
class Player
    def initialize(&block)
        @actions = {}
        instance_eval &block
    end
    def on(action, &block)
        @actions[action] = block
    end
    def act(action)
        @actions[action].call if @actions[action]
    end
end

melissa = Player.new do
  on :turn do
    puts "It's my turn!"
  end

  on :win do
    puts "I win! Hahahaha"
  end
end

melissa.act :turn   #=> It's my turn!
```

Comment: Amazing! I actually just came up with this solution myself. :)

Comment: Would it be possible to call send the block after the initialize? how DumpHole asked?

Comment: Also, this throws a `NoMethodError` `on` for `main:Object` in ruby 1.9.3